# UML diagrams used in the analysis stage

Tags: uml

Which of the uml diagrams are allowed to use in the software analysis phase?

Is the class diagram allowed to be used at the analysis stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ALL diagrams in an analysis phase - if it makes sense. Often during an analysis you document existing systems (in order to improve them). Obviously these systems (since they exist) have gone through all design stages. And (if documented) would have all needed model parts including UML diagrams. Of course in almost all cases this documentation does not exist.

If you are designing a system from scratch you would start with

- plain requirements
- synthesized use cases
- static class design
- behavioral

  - activity and
  - sequence diagram
  - eventually timing
- components (for larger systems)
- and finally deployment.

All of the above with back-cycles and different granularity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
I realized that in **analysis** phase, Class diagrams help discover the parts and their relationships at **conceptual level**. 
[Analysis vs. Design Class Diagram](https://imgur.com/a/xww84OM)

Comment: Exactly. When designing business objects you start with basic attributes and you go to a finer grain and more details over time. Which of tha above is actually needed depends on scope and goal of the design phase.